# Finding absolute position after a div was dropped into a new div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, position

The question almost says it all...

So. im using jQuery's drag and drop stuff, and I have the following problem.

I have a div #one and it can be dragged and then dropped into the div #two. Evereything works okay for now.

The thing is, that I want to save the position, where the #one was dropped. I get the position of #one with .position() - after dropping, I call .position() and the problem is that it calculates it's position relative to it's parent div (wrapper).

I want the script to calculate the position of #one relative to the #two (div where I dropped #one).

I cheated a bit, created #one immidiately in #two, and set it's left and top properties to -120px and 0px, so that the div would show outside #two, and when I dragged then #one into #two, I would get proper position.. But I don't want to do this like that..

Is there a way to find absolute position on #one relative to the #two after it was dropped in it ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be sufficient to add the coords of #two to the obtained relative position of #one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, You want to find position (left,top) of #one w.r.t #two. If so, you can use [.offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function to find the position of #two and #one and subtract their position to get the relative position of the #one inside #two.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/sMc7J/) here

Comment: mate, you answered my question, tried it, it works perfectly. Respect bro!